# How can I print to the console this table of numbers in Java?

Tags: java

Asking for a natural number n, I want to print to the console in this format:

```
                1
              2 1
            3 2 1
          4 3 2 1
        5 4 3 2 1
          .
          .
          .
n . . . 5 4 3 2 1
```

Inputting 4, this is what I have so far:

```
    1
   21
  321
 4321
```

I want to add a space between the numbers. This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PatternTwo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInput;
        System.out.println("Please enter a number 1...9 : ");
        userInput = in.nextInt();
        String s="";
        int temp = userInput;
        for(int i=1; i<=userInput; i++ ) {

            for (int k= userInput; k>=i; k-- ) {
                System.out.printf(" ");
            }

            for(int j =i; j>=1; j-- ) {
                System.out.print(j);
            }


            System.out.println("");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: So, add a space after System.out.print(j);

Comment: @Stultuske that results in a pyramid

Comment: @XtremeBaumer then he needs to add the print for the leading spaces in that loop as well. That doesn't change that if he wants to put spaces between those values, he should actually add a space between them.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, just wanted to compliment your code. It looks very good! Keep up the coding conventions :)

Comment: @Stultuske I never said that it is not what he should do, I just said, that your initial proposal is wrong

Comment: @XtremeBaumer incomplete, rather :)

Comment: kind of need to add an additional space before any output, be it a space or a digit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a space in front of the number to be printed and double the spaces above so that it is not a pyramid. Something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PatternTwo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInput;
        System.out.println("Please enter a number 1...9 : ");
        userInput = in.nextInt();
        String s="";
        int temp = userInput;
        for(int i=1; i<=userInput; i++ ) {

            for (int k= userInput; k>i; k-- ) { // <- corrected condition
                System.out.printf("  ");
            }

            for(int j = i; j>=1; j-- ) {
                System.out.print(j);

                // check if not 1 to avoid a trailing space
                if (j != 1) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }


            System.out.println("");
        }

    }

}
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to [/u/shash678](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6328256/shash678) I corrected my solution to remove all unnecessary or wrong spaces

Answer (score 1):

How about a cleaner solution, which avoids using nested for-loops:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a number 1...9 : ");
    final int n = scanner.nextInt();

    final ArrayList<String> suffixes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        suffixes.add(0, i + " ");

        final String prefix = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(n - i, "  "));
        final String suffix = String.join("", suffixes);

        System.out.println(prefix + suffix);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the String.join suggestion. But under the hood it is a for loop nonetheless ;)

Comment: True, but this is about readability and understandability, not performance optimization. :)

Answer (score 1):

Below is a modification of your answer that does not print unnecessary extra white space when `k` equals `i` by modifying your k for-loops exit condition and similarly when `j` equals `i` by dealing with that case separately.

The main overall change is that in your k-loop you need to print 2 spaces rather than 1 to achieve your desired right side alignment:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class PatternTwo {

  private static void printPatternTwo(int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      for (int k = n; k > i; k--) {
        System.out.print("  ");
      }
      for (int j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
        System.out.print(j == i ? j : " " + j);
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter an integer between 1 and 9 inclusive: ");
    int userNum = -1;
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
      if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        userNum = scanner.nextInt();
        if (userNum >= 1 && userNum <= 9) {
          scanner.close();
          break;
        } else {
          System.out.println("ERROR: Input number was not between 1 and 9");
          System.out.print("Enter a single digit number: ");
        }
      } else {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid Input");
        System.out.print("Please enter an integer between 1 and 9 inclusive: ");
        scanner.next();
      }
    }

    printPatternTwo(userNum);
  }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Please enter an integer between 1 and 9 inclusive: 12
ERROR: Input number was not between 1 and 9
Enter a single digit number: a
ERROR: Invalid Input
Please enter an integer between 1 and 9 inclusive: 5
        1
      2 1
    3 2 1
  4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: I corrected my mistake, thank you for bringing it up

Answer (score 0):

When printing the number put a space in from of it.

```
// this works up n == 9
System.out.print(" " + j);
```

For n > 9 the issue is that you need to print the number and whitespaces on a fixed amount of space however the number of chars a number contains changes. A solution would be to use tab (or several if you want really big numbers).

```
// when printing blank spaces use a tab instead
for (int k= userInput; k>=i; k-- ) {
    System.out.printf("\t");
}

// then print number with tab in front
for(int j =i; j>=1; j-- ) {
    System.out.print("\t"+j);
}
```

Comment: that results in a pyramid

Comment: @XtremeBaumer It really shouldn't. Actually I tested it and the output is what you expected.

Comment: I get a pyramid as well... You need to double the spaces above since we doubled the vertical size of the numbers compared to the spaces.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer updated the answer, should work with bigger numbers too. though I can't tell what is going on at like n > 100, my screen is not big enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with streams:

```
public class PatternTwo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userInput;
    System.out.println("Please enter a number 1...9 : ");
    userInput = in.nextInt();
    String s = "";
    int temp = userInput;

    revRange(1, temp).forEach(n -> printNumbers(n, temp));
  }

  static IntStream revRange(int from, int to) {
    return IntStream.range(from, to)
      .map(i -> to - i + from - 1);
  }

  private static void printNumbers(int n, int max) {
    IntStream.rangeClosed(0, n -1)
      .forEach(num -> System.out.print("  "));
    revRange(1, max - n)
      .forEach(num -> System.out.print(num + " "));
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative way could be to separate the spacing for each line using `printf`
and using `String.format` for each number.

```
String.format("%1$" + length + "s", inputString)
```

returns the `inputString` if `inputString.length` >= `length`else the inputString padded with spaces so that the length equal to the given length.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userInput;
    System.out.println("Please enter a number 1...9 : ");// you can use this also for numbers > 9
    userInput = in.nextInt();
    int digits = String.valueOf(userInput).length()+1;
    for(int i = 1; i<=userInput; i++){
        System.out.printf("%1$"+(digits*(userInput-i+1))+"s","");
        for(int k = userInput - (userInput-i); k >= 1; k--){
            System.out.print(String.format("%1$"+digits+"s", k));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```